# I am lost on how to filter mongoose data based on some options in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Nodejs api, I want users to be able to filter through data, like in the example below. I want users to be able to filter through `places` based on the `accessibility` or `amenities` of the place model.

I have tried populating through the data, but for some reason, it seems that isn't the way to go about it to filter the data.

Please how can I go about this to filter the data based on the requirement?

below is my model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    typeof: [{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["studio", "hall", 
                "house", "mansion",
                "field", "room",
                "restaurant", "school",
                "church"
            ]
    }],
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    location: {
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        state: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    amenities: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: ["electricity", "air conditioning", 
                "wifi", "Bathrooms", "Sound System", 
                "Private Entrance", "Sink", 
                "Kitchen", "Large table", 
                "Green Screen", "TV", "Stage", 
                "changing room", "makeup room",
                "lounge"
            ]
    }],
    accessibility: [{
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: ["Wheelchair accessible", "Elevator", 
                "On-site parking", "Parking near by",
                "Stairs"
            ]
    }],
    rules: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    isOpen: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: true
    },
    media: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Media',
        required: false,
    }],
    // image related end
}, {
    timestamps: true
})


const Place = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema)

module.exports = Place
```

and below is the get request

```
// get all places
router.get('/api/place', async (req, res) => {
    //  pagination and filter

    const noOnPage = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10
    const pageNo = (parseInt(req.query.page)-1)*parseInt(req.query.limit)

    try {
        const place = await Place.find({
            isOpen: true
        })
        .select('-media')
        .limit(noOnPage)
        .skip(pageNo)

        res.status(200).send(place)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

Here is how I tried populating which would not work

```
// get all places
router.get('/api/place', async (req, res) => {
    //  pagination and filter
    const match = {}

    if (req.query.amenities) {
        match.amenities = req.query.amenities
    }

    const noOnPage = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10
    const pageNo = (parseInt(req.query.page)-1)*parseInt(req.query.limit)

    try {
        const place = await Place.find({
            isOpen: true
        })
        .select('-media')
        .limit(noOnPage)
        .skip(pageNo)
        .populate({
            match
        }).exec()

        res.status(200).send(place)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

Comment: Show how you "tried populating through the data" and what errors you have. Current code in the question filters only by "isOpen" and should fork just fine.

Comment: @AlexBlex I just edited adding how I tried using populate

Comment: It explains. `populate` is to query referenced documents, something like "join" in SQL terms. In your case it's just a filter - the parameter of `.find()`, e.g. `Place.find({isOpen: true, amenities: "wifi"})`

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks a lot, you have been very helpful. it funny how the answer was right in front of me and I didn't realize it. you can update and give it as the answer so I can mark it.